# How to paginate a hash that's not an Active Record Object?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, pagination

So to my understanding, the `will_paginate` and `kaminari` gems work for paginating models and arrays. My problem is that I'm making a SQL call to a database and fetching a very large hash but I can't seem to paginate in any way. For will paginate I get the `invalid Active Record object`.

Comment: You can call `.to_a` on your `hash` and then call [`paginate`](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/74a6cd0197072903cd8b83744133744ff4b4c046/lib/will_paginate/array.rb#L16) on the array.

Comment: @ArupRakshit  Isn't the advantage of using `paginate` is that we don't fetch all records at once? If we do `to_a` after fetching all records, is there any advantage of pagination?

Comment: @WandMaker OP got hash, and wants to paginate it. That's the problem. That means OP pull all records.

Comment: How are you managing to read a Hash from DB?  What mechanism to you use?  Also, you call it very large hash - are you fetch whole table with many records?